# Define numeric constant in VS C++ (2013) project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to add define like this

```
#define API_VERSION 42
```

to VC++ project settings?

I tried in `Project Settings -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor definitions` but

```
API_VERSION 42
```

doesn't seem to work there, only

```
API_VERSION
```

which sets it to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set specific values, use `=`: `API_VERSION=42`

You separate additional defines with `;`: `API_VERSION=42;USE_DEBUG`

Comment: Yeah, seems to work. I used the separate editing window, here they are separated by newlines instead of `;`.